# Increase the size of a string in c#

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

I am trying to write a method that replaces a blank space in %20 in c#.  I am using stringBuilder to build the new string.  But I am running into an out of range exception, probably because the size of the array runs out.  Is there a way to increase the size of the string that I build using string

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    String add = "Mr John Smtih";
    Console.WriteLine(add);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(add);

    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < add.Length; i++)
    {
        if (add[i].Equals(' '))
        {
            sb[j] = '%';
            j++;
            sb[j] = '2';
            j++;
            sb[j] = '0';
        }
        else
        {
            sb[j] = add[i];
        }
        j++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(add);
    Console.WriteLine(sb);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: What about `add.Replace(" ", "%20")`?

Comment: You run into an Index out of range exception because you do someething OUTSIDE THE INDEX. I suggest you check the values you see in the debugger at the moment the exception occurs. It has nothning to do with StringBuilder running out of space - that one (RTFM) automatically readjusts the buffer upward when needed.

Comment: you can't index a StringBuilder with index if you don't add anything. Use sb.Append() instead, or better use the @im1dermike solution

Comment: You can do `new StringBuilder(add, 30)` if you want to initialize the [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx)  with a capacity of 30, for example.

Comment: Are you encoding a URL?  If so, you could use System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `String` class is immutable, so once you initialize it you cannot change the size of it.

You should use the `Append()` method in `StringBuilder`.  Your code would look something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    String add = "Mr John Smtih";
    Console.WriteLine(add);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < add.Length; i++)
    {
        if (add[i].Equals(' '))
        {
            sb.Append("%20");
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(add[i]);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(add);
    Console.WriteLine(sb);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to initialize a new, empty `StringBuilder`, and call `Append(char)` or the other appender methods on it repeatedly. Don't index into it.